# jquery find divs with id higher than some number

Tags: jquery

is there any way to find it?
for example:

```
var number=5;
$("#"+>number).remove();
```

but I dont know how do something like it and if is it posibble :)
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering if a custom selector is greater than a number in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356765/filtering-if-a-custom-selector-is-greater-than-a-number-in-jquery)

Comment: You should avoid numeric id. They cause problems, both for CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return parseInt( this.id, 10) > 5;
}).remove();
```

If `id` contains only `number`.

#### But you should avoid only numeric `id`.

***For example:***

```
<div id="myid-5"></div>
<div id="myid-6"></div>
```

And modify above code as:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return parseInt( this.id.replace('myid-',''), 10) > 5;
}).remove();
```

Comment: As far as the element is a div :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of the  `slice` function

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.

See http://api.jquery.com/slice/

This approach will help you get rid of the numerical indices

See [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/xEnN4/) on jsfiddle

Comment: slice works by count, not ID.  If he only had divs with ID 3, 4, 5 and wanted to get rid of 5 and above, your method would leave all 3.

Comment: Yes, by count. But my method allow to work with DOM elements without unnecessary relations (between CSS-selectors and JS)